# Extract frames from .evo files/movies

Tags: python, type-conversion, mp4, evo

I'm trying to extract frames from a .evo files.

I tried .VideoCapture from the cv2 module. It did extract frames but they were all grey.

I also used ffmpeg in the terminal to convert the .evo in a .mp4 movie -> Same result, just movie with only grey frames.

My question is: is it possible to convert an .evo file in a .mp4/.mov format for instance ? If yes, How ?

Thanks in advance everyone !

Comment: where is the evo file coming from?

Comment: From OpenFoam, I tried both on Mac and Windows, I always get the same error message: No JPEG data found in image

Comment: I guess it comes from the decoding, but I don't know how to resolve this issue since there is very little info about .evo files...